# Unable to collect the result of my LINQ query into a custom Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have a class with the name Donut

```
 public class Donut
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a LINQ (Union) query ...

```
List<Donut> myData = (from items in db.form1_tbl_pop
                              select new
                              {
                                  Name = "Urban",
                                  Y = Convert.ToInt32(db.form1_tbl_pop.Sum(a => a.u))
                              })
                            .Union(from items in db.form1_tbl_pop
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       Name = "Rural",
                                       Y = Convert.ToInt32(db.form1_tbl_pop.Sum(a => a.r))
                                   }
                ).ToList();
```

I want to collect the result of the query into list of type Donut but the system is throwing the following exception.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Name, int Y>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DummyApp.Models.Donut>
```

Kindly let me know what's wrong with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write not just `select new` but `select new Donut{...}`. In case of just `select new` dotnet runtime creates a new anonymous type `anonymous type: string Name, int Y`.

Comment: Oh... Wasted alot of time to fix this bug... Thank you alot...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in your `select` statements you're creating new anonymous objects, you need to create new `Donut` objects:

```
List < Donut > myData = (from items in db.form1_tbl_pop select new Donut() {
  Name = "Urban",
   Y = Convert.ToInt32(db.form1_tbl_pop.Sum(a => a.u))
 })
 .Union(from items in db.form1_tbl_pop select new Donut(){
  Name = "Rural",
   Y = Convert.ToInt32(db.form1_tbl_pop.Sum(a => a.r))
 }).ToList();
```